# push to array getting the file from firestore javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I try to push an array that I got from firestore, but when I try it's undefined

this is the code

```
  const tmp = [];
  const ref = firestore.collection("users").doc(user?.uid);
  firestore
    .collection("countrys")
    .get()
    .then((x) => {
      x.forEach((y) => {
        tmp.push(y.data());
      });
    });
  console.log(tmp); //work
  console.log(tmp[0]); //no work
```

this is the result from the console

[image]

as I see it's not same like another array

another array like `(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]` ,but my array just show `[]`

can someone explain to me why that's not working? thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @DaneBrouwer sorry I'm already read it but I'm still don't understand, can you give me some example or code?

Comment: What kind of array are you expecting? Can you add a sample ? Can you please try `console.log(JSON.stringify(tmp))` ? and share the screenshot of it ?

Comment: `tmp` is undefined because the code you're running is asynchronous, and you're logging `tmp` synchronously.

Comment: @DaneBrouwer do you know how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you've mixed [asynchronous](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_asynchronous.asp) code with synchronous code.
To clarify further, `firestore.collection("countrys").get()` is a `promise`.

So if you want to interact with the data it returns just do it in your `.then()`

```js
firestore
  .collection("countrys")
  .get()
  .then((querySnapshot) => {
    const tmp = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      tmp.push(doc.data());
    });
    console.log(tmp);
    console.log(tmp[0]);
  });
```

I would suggest doing some further reading into [promises](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_promise.asp) as well.

Comment: I try to return it but got undefined , can you help me ?

Comment: Does your collection actually have data? Is `countrys` correctly spelled? (The correct plural spelling is `countries`) Because the above is directly from [Firestore's documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection)

Comment: I add my answer below, hope you can understand

Comment: Edit your answer below into your question, don't add a new answer. It's still asynchronous, if you need to interact with `tmp` do it inside of the `.then`. You cannot access it outside of `.then`.

Answer (score 0):

the console.log(temp) will execute before the

```
x.forEach((y) => {
    tmp.push(y.data());
 });
```

code will occur.

You need to add another .then chained to the then method so it will execute when the promise resolve to make the console log succeeded.

This is part of the event loop in JS.

I recommend to read more about it here:

https://blog.sessionstack.com/how-javascript-works-event-loop-and-the-rise-of-async-programming-5-ways-to-better-coding-with-2f077c4438b5

And more about promises here:

https://web.dev/promises/